# Unable to get the data from the json response with multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jsonresponse

Below is the exact json response in which I need to retrieve the value of "count(dm_document.object_name)". I am not understanding to to parse this. pLease help.

```
{
"status":"ok",
"data":

    [
     [
      {
        "dataType":"Double",
        "count(dm_document.object_name)":5,"repeating":false
      }
     ]
    ],
    "hostName":"XXXX-prf-08.portal.XXX.com","code":1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when developing an iOS application. I used a library which binds the json data to the objects. It automatically binds the data after you define the objects. I don't know the language you use, but I used [this.](http://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) 
I hope it gives you an opinion.